# Magento pdf file on view page

Tags: magento

I want to add a .pdf document file for user(s) to read on the view page in magento.
I have added the file by using WYSIWYG editor,but it shows a downloadable link which i don't want. I just want to view the inner pdf contents on the page.

Please help.

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Hey problem solved.You can do that by usin google docs. tyr it...enjoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want pdf viewer plugin.
Just check this out. I think it will be helpful for you. I didn't use that. Just googled and found.

http://groupdocs.com/marketplace/plugins/viewer/magento